# Why explicit Integer conversion doesn't apply as expected

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision, floating-accuracy

**Please be aware that my question is not "Why do floating numbers lose precision"** I am aware that not all fractional parts of a number can sit in binary form. What's really stored is actually the ''closest number ''
occupied all Mantissa bit space.

Given:

```
//This is just an example.
float f1 = 17.96f, f3 = 17.98f;
double d2 = 17.96, d4 = 17.98;
printf("1. 17.96 = %f (as cents:%d)\n", price1, (int)(f1 * 100));
printf("2. 17.96 = %lf (as cents:%d)\n", price2, (int)(d2 * 100));
printf("3. 17.98 = %f (as cents:%d)\n", price3, (int)(f3 * 100));
printf("4. 17.98 = %lf (as cents:%d)\n", price4, (int)(d4 * 100));
```

the output is

```
1. 17.96 = 17.959999 (as int:1795)
2. 17.96 = 17.960000 (as int:1796)
3. 17.98 = 17.980000 (as int:1798)
4. 17.98 = 17.980000 (as int:1798)
```

I changed the printing format to the 25th decimal place to see what is the "real number" stored in memory.
The output turns out

```
1. 17.96 = 17.9599990844726562500000000 (as int:1795)
2. 17.96 = 17.9600000000000008526512829 (as int:1796)
3. 17.98 = 17.9799995422363281250000000 (as int:1798)
4. 17.98 = 17.9800000000000004263256415 (as int:1798)
```

The question is why (int)(f1* 100) results in 1795 instead of 1796 according to the ''real stored number'' is 17.9599990844726562500000000.

But (int)(f3 * 100) results in 1798 instead of 1797.while''real stored number'' is 17.9799995422363281250000000. "the" real number * 100 equals 1797.99995422363281250000000. So after Integer Truncation, it's supposed to be 1797 but I got 1798.

Comment: Why aren't you asking your teaching staff about this? By all means, ask around the internet and do your own research... but your teaching staff is paid to help you with this stuff. I don't understand why you'd ignore that resource.

Comment: Your *Part B* question is entirely inappropriate for this site. We don't offer career, study, educational, or other advice. This site is specifically for questions related to programming  (code) or use of a programmer's tool. For *Part A*, why aren't you asking your instructor this question? They're being paid to educate you, and part of their job is making information clear and providing additional explanation when it is not.

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think your biggest problem is that you believe AI is actual artificial intelligence, despite it's name and sometimes appearance it's not the least bit intelligent, all LLTs do is crunche the numbers and predict the next word, you would be ***way*** better off asking fellow students or your teaching staff.

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: To answer this, print out `price3 * 100` (without casting), to 25th decimal place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common `float` and `double` are some integer times a power of 2.  See [Dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

`17.96` and `17.98` are **not** representable *exactly* that way.

Instead a nearby representable number is used which is just above or just below the desired code floating point constant.

```
printf("%.52e %.52e\n", 17.96f, 17.98f);
printf("%.52e %.52e\n", 17.96, 17.98);
1.7959999084472656250000000000000000000000000000000000e+01 1.7979999542236328125000000000000000000000000000000000e+01
1.7960000000000000852651282912120223045349121093750000e+01 1.7980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875000e+01
```

Scaling by 100 incurs *additional* rounding effects - perhaps up a tad or down a little.  The products may be 1796, 1798 or just above or just below.

Recall `17.96f * 100` is **not** the same as math 17.96 * 100, but `17.95999908447265625f * 100.0f` (which is 1795.999908447265625) and then that product is rounded to the nearest `float`: 1795.9998779296875.

```
printf("%.52e %.52e\n", 17.96f * 100, 17.98f * 100);
printf("%.52e %.52e\n", 17.96 * 100, 17.98 * 100);
1.7959998779296875000000000000000000000000000000000000e+03 1.7980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e+03
1.7960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e+03 1.7980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e+03
```

[Edit]
OP added <"the" real number * 100 equals 1797.99995422363281250000000>
That is true math wise, yet it is a `float` multiplication with a `float` product.  As 1797.9999542236328125 is not representable as a `float`, the result was rounded to 1 or 2 nearby `float`s: 1797.9998779296875 or 1798.0.  With OP's FP rounding mode, it likely rounded to the nearest: 1798.0.  Converting that to an `int` is 1798.

---

C23 optionally offers decimal floating point and that is best used for like decimal problems.

---

Do not use crude casts like `(int)` on the results of floating point calculation without a clear understanding of the edge effects.

Applying an `int` cast is questionable coding as the  product calculations may result in 1796, or 1798 as the prior product was 1795.999... 1797.999...  Using `lround()` would make more sense.

---

To well scale money using `float` (a poor idea), multiply by 100.0 (a `double`) and use `llround()` or `lround()`.

To well scale money using `double` into an integer, multiply by 100.0L (a `long double`) and use `llroundl()` or `lroundl()`.

The extra precision will help with edge cases.

```
printf("%ld %ld\n", lround(17.96f * 100.0), lround(17.98f * 100.0));
printf("%lld %lld\n", llroundl(17.96 * 100.0L), llroundl(17.98 * 100.0L));
1796 1798
1796 1798
```

---

Note `17.96f * 100` is like `17.96f * 100.0f` - a `float` multiplication. That differs from `17.96f * 100.0` - a `double` multiplication.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. I've known that floating numbers stored in the system are not actually the numbers themselves unless their fractional part is 1/2^n. So I changed the print format up to 25 decimal places to check the " nearest number". 17.96f = 17.9599990844726562500000000 (as cents:1795)  17.98f = 17.9799995422363281250000000 (as cents:1798)   .  after * 100 then explicitly convert to Int , first one rounded down to 1795 , second didn't round down to 1797 . That's what I can't figure. I asked my school instructor she couldn't tell. So I think 7th decimal number decide it

Comment: and I am also confused about this part Recall 17.96f * 100 is not the same as math 17.96 * 100, but 1.795999908447265625f * 100.0f (which is 179.5999908447265625), and then that product is rounded to the nearest float: 179.59998779296875. 17.96f x100 is 1.795999908447265625f * 100.0f , why it's not  17.95999908447265625f x 100f? and I think 100 does not matter whether it's 100.0f (as a float) or 100 (as Int) It won't impact the result because the "fractional part " is 0 which makes it perfectly stored in the mantissa bit space.

Comment: @MarlonB [That's what I can't figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131363/a-topic-that-has-been-discussed-exhaustively-precision-between-double-and-flo/77131491?noredirect=1#comment135985297_77131491) --> What is `17.979999542236328125f * 100`? Math wise, the product is `1797.9999542236328125`, yet that is not representable as a `float`.  The closest `float` is `1798.0f`.  Converting that to an `int` is `1798`.

Comment: @MarlonB Re: [and I am also confused ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131363/a-topic-that-has-been-discussed-exhaustively-precision-between-double-and-flo/77131491?noredirect=1#comment135985721_77131491): clerical error fixed in answer.

Comment: Thanks for your supplementary explanation. now I finally understand that.